# How to add a layout to current Main Activity layout using Thread in Android

Tags: android

This is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

And this is class that will excute a Thread

```
public class Ads implements Runnable {

    private Activity activity;

    public Ads(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = activity;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(activity);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 75, Gravity.CENTER);
        TextView txt = new TextView(activity);
        txt.setText("ASD");
        layout.addView(txt);
        activity.getWindow().addContentView(layout, params);
    }

}
```

I ran this code but my application could'nt start. How to add a layout to current activity? Plz help me, tks

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize your UI from a worker thread. You have to do this in the main thread. A thread will be only use to make some complex calcul. Everything is here :http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

You can add a initUI function

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initUI();
}


private void initUI() {
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 75, Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("ASD");
    layout.addView(txt);
    getWindow().addContentView(layout, params);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If Class `Ads`'s `run()` executes in a thread, that is not the main UI thread (the one where `onCreate()` executes), then, inside `run()` you cannot make changes to UI views.

Hence, execute the code which makes changes to UI using [`runOnUIThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable{
 @Override
 public void run(){
   //make changes to UI here--
 }
});
```

By the way, you can place that code in `onCreate()` only, it's not doing much work.

Also, [this training article](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) explains communication with UI Thread in detail.